# how to apply parLapply to evaluate a triangle matrix

Tags: r

I have a triangle matrix of  very large size and want to evaluate it with snow (MPI) on a cluster.

Suppose my matrix has 6 rows and 6 columns which means the first row has 6 elements , the second row has 5 elements,`````the sixth row has 1 elements. Each elements has 2 variables (x1, x2), so that each element is a function of x1 and x2. Different elements have different x1 and x2. I want to send all the x1 and x2 to the nodes and let them evaluate the matrix.

Suppose I have 3 nodes (workers). I want the first node to evaluate the first and sixth rows, the second node evaluates the second and fifth rows and the third node evaluates the third and fourth rows, so that the three nodes has the same amount of load. After they finish, they send back the rows and forms a triangle matrix in the master node.

Can anyone help me with that? Really appreciate it!

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: lmgtfy [link](http://www.sfu.ca/~sblay/R/snow.html), as to snow; are your elements in the very large triangle of c++ type double, integer, short or char? Probably best to focus first on the matrix and then the snow implementation. I second Roman.  HTH